# How can I stream markup data into an Android webview without breaking access to http:// or file:///android_asset?

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview

**Background:** I have a working application which populates webview data by reading the response from an `HttpURLConnection`, running some processing on the markup, and then feeding the complete string to `WebView.loadDataWithBaseUrl` to display the page. This approach works, but has the performance drawback of eliminating concurrent processing of the partially loaded document which happens by default when loading a page normally in any browser or webview.

**Goal:** I'd like to change my application to a streaming model instead of a two-step serial process. In short, I'm investigating whether I can move from this:

1. Open the response stream from the server.
2. Block and read everything from the server until end of document.
3. Hand the whole thing to the webview at once.

to this:

1. Open the response stream from the server.
2. Read any available data and hand it immediately to the webview.
3. Repeat 2 until end of document.

For an additional wrinkle, the webview pages use both http:// and file:///android_asset requests, which work fine in my current setup. My main difficulty preserving access to both of these. Sidenote: I'm supporting API v14+.

Here's a simplified code summary of my current attempt.

```
// -- Setup --

WebView webview = makeWebView(); // WebSettings, JS on, view setup, etc
String url = "http://mywebsite.com";
InputStream is = getResponseStreamFromNetwork(url);


// -- Current data injection code --

String completeMarkup = readEverythingAtOnce(is);
webview.loadDataWithBaseUrl(url, completeMarkup, "text/html", "UTF-8", url);


// -- Ideal future data injection code --

webview.loadDataWithBaseUrl(url, "", "text/html", "UTF-8", url);
String line = null;
while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {
  appendToWebView(webview, line);
}
finishWebView(webview);


// -- The hard bits --

void appendToWebView(WebView webview, String line) {
  // Inject a partial markup string to the end of the webview's content.
  webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.write('" + line.replace("'", "\\'") + "\\n');");
}

void finishWebView(WebView webview) {
  // We're done injecting data. Tell the webview we're finished if needed.
  webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.write('\\n\\n');");
  webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.close();");
}
```

As written, this successfully streams markup to the webview via `document.write`, and the page is properly displayed, but my file:///android_asset data requests all get denied access. Changing the base URL of `loadDataWithBaseUrl` to file:///android_asset fixes those but breaks access to http:// requests via XmlHttpRequest. I *assume* that this is by-design same origin policy specifically for content introduced via `document.write`. If that's the case, is there an alternative method for injecting this content piece by piece?

In short, is there a way to reimplement `appendToWebView` and `finishWebView` or change something elsewhere to stream data into the webview while avoiding this access problem?

Comment: I see no reason for appendToWebView. Nor do i see that such could work. Just let the WebView load the page itself. Then call finishWebView in onPageLoaded.

Comment: greenapps: I'm required to perform app-side processing on the markup before handing it off to the webview. Otherwise, I would just defer to the webview itself to load the page as you suggest and none of this would be a problem. It's very possible that piece-by-piece injection with the requirements above isn't feasible at all, but I'm holding out hope that I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes, mixing http(s) and file:// scheme is going to break due to the same origin policy.

This should work instead:

- host your entire contents under a 'virtual' http(s) URL (ideally one that you own, or use androidplatform.net),
- use WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest to intercept the requests to the 'virtual' URL and provide either the network InputStream or an InputStream associated with the asset.

Edit: The relevant bit of code the WebView uses to handle file://android_asset URLs is [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/android_webview/java/src/org/chromium/android_webview/AndroidProtocolHandler.java).

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought of this. I'm already intercepting requests and filtering my markup for other purposes, so I should be able to rewrite file:/// URLs on the inbound and provide content directly on the outbound fairly easily. Giving it a shot and will follow up with results and an accept.

Comment: @Mian - in case you still need it (and for the benefit of others) I have added the link to the code the WebView uses to handle android_asset URLs